# File upload in C#

Tags: asp.net

I'm sending a file to my backend C# (ASP.NET) from the front end Angular 6. And  want to save that file in a folder in the backend server and save that path in the MS SQL database.

```
   [EnableCors(origins: " * ", headers: " * ", methods: " * ")]  
    [AcceptVerbs("GET", "POST")]  
    [HttpGet]  
    [Route("CustomerSignature/Upload")]  
    public virtual IHttpActionResult Upload(int value)  
    {  
        string imageName = null;  
        string statuscode = " - 1";  
        string message = "";  

        HttpResponseMessage response = Request.CreateResponse();  





        try  
        {  

            var httpRequest = HttpContext.Current.Request;  

        }  
        catch (SqlException sqlex)  
        {  
            statuscode = "- 1";  
            response.StatusCode = HttpStatusCode.NotFound;  
            response.Headers.Add("Error", sqlex.Message);  
            message = ERPMessages.GetMessage(MessageType.FindByErrorSQL, this.Controller);  
        }  
        catch (Exception ex)  
        {  
            statuscode = " - 2";  
            response.StatusCode = HttpStatusCode.NotFound;  
            response.Headers.Add("Error", ex.Message);  
            message = ERPMessages.GetMessage(MessageType.FindByErrorGenaral, this.Controller);  
        }  
        return new MergeResult(response, statuscode, message, 0);  
    }  
}
```

In above, After reading the "HttpContext.Current.Request", How to get the file that is in the request and save it in folder and save the file path in the data base? Please help me to solve this issue.

Comment: Taking image in multipart formdata?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try something similar to below:

```
 public HttpResponseMessage Post()  
 {  
     HttpResponseMessage result = null;  
     var httpRequest = HttpContext.Current.Request;  
     if (httpRequest.Files.Count > 0)  
     {  
          var filePathCollection = new List<string>();  
          foreach (string file in httpRequest.Files)  
          {  
              var postedFile = httpRequest.Files[file];  
              var filePath = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/" + postedFile.FileName);  
              postedFile.SaveAs(filePath);  
              filePathCollection.Add(filePath);

          }  

          /// Save FilePathcollection in SQL Server
          result = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.Created, docfiles);  
      }  
      else  
      {  
          result = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);  
      }  

      return result;  
}
```